# Variables seem the same but don't match

Tags: arrays, string, powershell, variables, if-statement

I am trying to compare 2 values in variables to see if they're the same, in the PowerShell output I can see that some combinations should be true!

First, without the making of `$vergelijking1` and `$vergelijking2` it showed as if `$nummersPOs[$counter]` and `$object.'col1'` were the same but the if statement was never true.

The only thing I could think of as to why it would fail is that 1 of the variables comes from an array. When I changed both types to String I could indeed see that there was some hidden text but I don't understand why my if statment is never true now. It writes "test2" but should write "inside the loop".

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$data = Import-Csv "C:\Users\UserName\Documents\test.csv"
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$NummersPOs = Import-Csv "C:\Users\UserName\Documents\test.csv" | select "col1" -Unique
$counter = 0

foreach ($object in $NummersPOs) {
    $newCSV = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
    foreach ($object in $data) {
        if ($object."col2") {
            $index = $newCSV.Add($object)
            [string]$vergelijking1 = $NummersPOs[$counter]
            #$vergelijking1 = $vergelijking1 -replace '\D+(\d+)','$1'
            $vergelijking1
            [string]$vergelijking2 = $object.'col1'
            $vergelijking2
            if ($vergelijking1 -contains $vergelijking2) {
                Write-Host "inside the loop"
            } else {
                Write-Host "test2"
            }
        }
    }
    $counter++
}
$newCSV | Export-Csv "C:\Users\UserName\Documents\test2.csv"
```

Sample output:

```
@{col1=632424}
632424
test2
@{col1=632424}
632446
test2
```

As you can see, the first one should have been true already. `-contain` or `-like` both give false BTW.

Comment: `-contains` only works on collections. Compare with `$vergelijking1 -like "*$vergelijking2*"` instead

Answer (score 0):

Take an actual look at your operands:

```
"@{col1=632424}"    ← $vergelijking1
"632424"            ← $vergelijking2
```

These two strings are obviously **not** equal, so why would you expect them to be?

You're assigning an object to `$verglijking1` and cast it to a string, so you actually get a string representation of that object (`@{col1=632424}`). To `$verglijking2` you assign the *value of an object property* (`$object.'col1'`). Even though you still cast the value to a string you only get the string representation of the *value*, not of the *object*.

Also, you can't use the [`-contains` operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx), as [@Mathias R. Jesson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39827537/variables-seem-the-same-but-dont-match-powershell#comment66946167_39827537) pointed out, since that operator is for checking the presence of elements in an array. The `-like` operator would've worked, but you'd have to put [wildcards](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717088%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) before and after the value (`"*$verglijking2*"`). Without wildcards the operator behaves exactly like the `-eq` operator.

With that said, all the casting you do in your script is completely unnecessary. Handle both variables the same way and use the correct comparison operator, and the problem will disappear.

```
if ($object.col2) {
    $vergelijking1 = $NummersPOs[$counter].col1
    $vergelijking2 = $object.col1
    if ($vergelijking1 -eq $vergelijking2) {
        Write-Host "inside the loop"
    } else {
        Write-Host "test2"
    }
}
```